# How to profile an OpenEdge database?

Tags: profiling, progress-4gl, openedge

Is there a Progress profiling tool that allows me to see the queries executing against an OpenEdge database?

We're doing a migration from an OpenEdge database into a SQL database.  In order to map the data correctly we'd like to run certain application reports on the OpenEdge database and see what database queries are being executed to retrieve the data.

Is this possible with some kind of Progress profiling tool (a la SQL Server Profiling)?  Preferably free...

Comment: Is it a commercial application?  There are many "well known" (at least well known to Progress people) commercial applications written in Progress and there may be people available who can help guide you.  But first they would need to know what the application is.

Answer (score 2):

Progress is record oriented, not set oriented like SQL, so your reports aren't a single query or a set of queries, it is more likely a lot of record lookups combined with what you'd consider query-like operations.

Depending on the version you're running, there is a way to send a signal to the client to see what it is currently doing, however doing so will almost certainly **not** give you enough information to discern what's going on "under the hood."

Long story short, your options are to get a [Dataserver product](https://www.progress.com/openedge/features/operational-excellence/dataservers) so you can attach the Progress client to an SQL database - this will enable you to use an SQL database w/out losing the Progress functionality. The second option is to get a copy of the program's source code to find out how the reports are structured.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I've been told that I would need to recompile the ABL in order to run against a SQL backend through a dataserver - is that correct?

Comment: I have no experience with the Dataserver product, so I can't say with authority. My _guess_ would be that you'd need to recompile if the table structure under a DS is different than one seen using a Progress db connection.

Answer (score 2):

Tim is quite right -- without the source code, looking at the queries is unlikely to provide you with much insight.

None the less there are some tools and capabilities that will provide information about queries.  Probably the most useful for your purpose would be to specify something similar to:

```
 -logentrytypes QryInfo -logginglevel 3 -clientlog "mylog.log"
```

at session startup.

Comment: I've found that I need to lower the -logginglevel to 2 else the program crashes.  Any ideas?

Comment: Crashes generally have error messages associated with them.  Those error messages often point the way towards solving problems.  Since I do not know what errors you are experiencing and do not know of any widely experienced errors resolved by lowering the logging level (other than running out of disk space -- but that seems too obvious) I don't really have anything to offer in the way of solutions.

Comment: Sure, the crash has no detail to help me without the source.  No worries.

Comment: You "crashed" with no error messages?  That  seems very strange.  In any  case, as mentioned above and in the other answers -- without the source you are probably not really not going to get very far anyway.

Comment: There was an exception report but it contained guids, memory pointers and procedure names only, nothing english or readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session triggers to identify almost anything done by any program, without modifying or having access to the source of those programs. Setting this up may be more work than is worth it for your purpose. We have a testing system built around this idea. One big flaw: triggers cannot be fired for CAN-FIND.

Comment: Adding session triggers will interfere with the application if it uses triggers for the events you add. The trigger defined last will prevail, the other wont be executed. The FIND trigger you'd need to add is AFAIK not frequently used, but in OpenEdge V8 we used it for calculated fields in browsers.

Comment: Good point. It's also worth noting that triggers may not fire exactly the way you expect - eg. IIRC (and I may not be) you won't see create/update/delete triggers until the transaction is committed, which may be far away from the related CREATE or DELETE statement.